# ServiceHost.Behaviours .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

To solve an error I've been experiencing with my WCF application, I've been looking to set the Behaviour property as follows (ref https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web-receiving-arbitrary-data/):

```
 serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyClass), new Uri(endpoint));
 serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyInterface), GetBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

The confusing part is the Behaviour property doesn't seem to be available in .NET 4.5, only the earlier versions of the framework (4.0 backwards). Can anyone point me towards the new implementation for this property as using the older framework breaks my build of other projects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some reason the property is enabled in .NET 4.6.1 so I've upgraded to that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API hasn't changed in 4.5.

To add a behavior to an endpoint, use the `EndpointBehaviors` property:

```
endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

To add a behavior to a service, use:

```
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());
```